# Blank screen appears when i try to open Jmeter in GUI mode in Cent OS

Tags: linux, jmeter

I am setting up a new Jmeter 5.0 on Cent OS. I tried to open it in GUI mode using terminal.

I also tried to replace all lib jars and open Jmeter using terminal.

Jmeter must open in GUI mode so i can debug my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Jmeter/bin/ 
execute the below command in the terminal

```
sh jmeter.sh
```

Hopefully you can see the GUI.